# How to take this element inside array

Tags: php

Hello,
I will take a specific element inside this code. just ambassador-main-logo.png
My problem is this element can change `4 =>` and take another number. Goal save the image inside db.

for example work but not if the number change.

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name[4][image], $directory . $name[4][image]
```

Tk

```
array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => string 'ambassador-main-logo.png' (length=24)
  'type' => 
    array (size=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => string '/tmp/phpJQs3TX' (length=14)
  'error' => 
    array (size=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
      'image' => int 61261
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have this one element inside your arrays, you can use `array_keys()` function to find out, what the index is.

It should look like this:

```
$keys = array_keys($tmp); // Find all the keys of your array
$filename = $tmp['name'][$keys[0]]['image']; // Access the filename
```

Reference: https://secure.php.net/array_keys